# No Matching provisioning profiles found ios7 xcode5

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I am having a fairly annoying problem with my provisioning profile, The app I am working on started off with a name lets call it awesomeapp, so in the provisioning portal at apple I have a ios app identifier with the id "com.mydomain.awesomeapp".

but my apps bundle identifier is called AwesomeApp, and it turns out that the provisioning profile that is used the app identifier I have created is case sensitive. as I get this error

> The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“iOS Team
>   Provisioning Profile: com.mydomain.awsmomeapp”) has an AppID of
>   “com.mydomain.awsomeapp” which does not match your bundle identifier
>   “com.mydomain.AwsomeApp”.  Xcode can resolve this issue by
>   downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.

If I click okay it goes ahead and removes the provisioning profile and uses a wildcard one i set up.. However I dont want to use the wild card provisioning profile.

So, I went back to create a new app identifier and I entered the id to be **com.mydomain.AwsomeApp** however this prompts an error

> An App ID with Identifier 'com.mydomain.AwesomeApp' is not available.
>   Please enter a different string.

which suggests to me that when you create an app ID it is case Insensitive.. how do I get around this problem?

Comment: So I have fixed this by changing mydomain to something else and then editing that in the bundle identifier in xcode 5... but the question still stands as imo something is wrong there that apple should fix.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no other solution than deleting the app id and recreating it with the proper identifier.

Originally Apple had no options to **edit**, **rename** or **delete** an `App-Id` at all.
However at some point in 2013 they've added an delete button available in your members

*provisioning center -> App-Id -> Edit one specific -> delete*

Some users have reported, that the **delete** button has been disabled again but for me, it is still working:

[image]

Comment: I just want to tell you that I love you! I spent 3 hours in the search of this answer!! Thank you!